# Help Identifying Bike Frame?

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

Trying to identify this bike frame so I can build it with compatible components, AND so I can calculate it's value. Any help massively appreciated.

[image: bike frame #1]

Comment: How did it end with all identifying details removed and in your possession? The easiest way is usually just asking the seller.

Comment: I would say "Chinese".

Comment: @ojs I found one of my frames literally hanging out of a trash bin. (It's rusted and ugly, but it still rides well.) If it weren't for (1) the bottom bracket stamp and (2) this sort of vintage steel bike being very popular where I live, I would probably have asked a similar question. Though I suppose people taking out the trash and coming back into their apartments with a 40 year old bike frame isn't a common occurrence, it has made me consider that situations like OP's might be similar.

Comment: @jayded-bee your story does not really help with identifying this one, but thank you anyway

Comment: @ojs My comment wasn't about identifying this particular frame, just pointing out that (a) the frame might not _have_ a seller _to_ ask and/or that (b) OP has likely already exhausted their options as far as asking the previous owner goes. (At least, my first assumption is that the questioner had done the bare minimum before posting online.)

Comment: Does it matter in the slightest ?   What you need is compatible components, which are based on measurements.  What brand it was is irrelevant now.   Do note that you'll never get a rear derailleur on this bike, and even a front one might be impossible, giving you one speed (gear ratio)  If you want to progress this, start by finding a seat post and clamp that fits this frame properly.  That's your biggest challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Actual identification may be difficult. Valuing a frame whose provenance you can’t show is is also difficult. It is possible for me to say a few things.

1. This is an aluminum frame with an aero downtube and a cutout in the seat tube. And it may take an aerodynamic seatpost, which unfortunately tend to be proprietary to the frame unless the seat tube is round. You will need to check this.
2. It has what I would normally call track dropouts in the rear. It also has a guide near the head tube (in the downtube) for internal cable routing. Thus it probably isn't a track frame (you could measure the distance between the dropouts to confirm, track frames are 120mm vs 130mm for road). There should be some sort of screw in each dropout to help you adjust how close the wheel sits to the seat tube.
3. I would have guessed this could be a Cervelo, maybe mid 2000s or early 2010s. However, see the area on the chainstay just above the dropouts? I don’t know that Cervelo ever used that shape. There are no visual matches on [this vintage Cervelo bike website](https://vintagecervelo.weebly.com/dual.html).
4. I would guess this is a triathlon or time trial frame. There weren't many aero road frames from the time period I think this frame is from. One of the prominent aluminum aero road frames from that era was the Cervelo Soloist, and we've established that the dropout design is wrong for Cervelo.

Comment: The combination of aero features, horizontal dropouts and internal routing ports is indeed very odd.  My guess would be some sort of generic aero bike that's had different dropouts fitted to make a track/fixie varient

Answer (score 0):

It looks **similar** to an early `90s road bike I had from Mongoose (yes the BMX makers) but with some differences.

[image]

Dropped chainstay and high-aspect ratio downtube are similar.

Yours has trackends not dropouts and might have a 120 mm OLD measurement.
Also your top tube is more formed whereas mine was a chunky tube, and a more aggressively aero seat tube+post.

There are many more photos in https://criggie.org.nz/pictures/bikes/mongoose/

We don't really do valuations, other than Aluminium is worth around $6 a kilo as scrap metal, very region-dependent.   A bare frame with no provenance and a lot of missing parts before its a bike, is just scrap metal until you build it into a working rideable bike.   You don't even have a fork and that's hard to match.

Comment: Never mind the fork. If the OP needs a non-round seat collar like it looks like this Mongoose has, or a non-round seatpost, those seem likely to be proprietary items. If those are needed, then I have a feeling the project is DOA.

Comment: @WeiwenNg i did a bit more digging into this rather strange combination of frame features this evening.  I couldn't find an exact match, but it seems frames in this style have some popularity amongst 'trendy' fixie designs.  The internal routing on the top tube is used for a rear brake.  With a seeming abundance of similar bikes available it's possible OP might be able to get some compatible parts